# Cannot update mule version to 3.6 in esb mule maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, mule, esb

i am using Anypoint Studio (latest version to date)

i cant find what is wrong, everything messes up when i change the mule-version to 3.6

this is **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hamgam.esb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ESBDroolsRouter</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule DroolsJBPM Application</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.6.0</mule.version>
        <!-- Tools properties -->
        <eclipsePluginVersion>2.5</eclipsePluginVersion>
        <vmtype>org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType</vmtype>
        <jdkName>JavaSE-1.7</jdkName>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <!--
            Use a newer version of the install plugin than what your Maven uses by default. The
            older version failed to install the project if there was no target/classes folder.
            Since we use mule packaging on the project we actually create and attach the zip that
            must be installed.
        -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipsePluginVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- by default download all sources when generating project files -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/${vmtype}/${jdkName}
                        </classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                make sure that MULE_HOME is set when building (required below when copying the
                artifact to Mule's apps directory
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireProperty>
                                    <property>env.MULE_HOME</property>
                                    <message>You must set MULE_HOME before installing the example.</message>
                                </requireProperty>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                automatically deploy the artifact after it has been built
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-example</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip"
                                    todir="${env.MULE_HOME}/apps" overwrite="true"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- plugins for creating site reports -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>http://mulesoft.org/download/attachments/92/checkstyle.xml?version=1</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>${jdk.version}</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>TODO</tag>
                        <tag>@todo</tag>
                        <tag>FIXME</tag>
                        <tag>@fixme</tag>
                        <tag>@deprecated</tag>
                    </tags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-bpm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-drools</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-jbpm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mockobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockobjects-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.09</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GOLI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>muleforge-repo</id>
            <name>MuleForge Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.muleforge.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-repo</id>
            <name>Codehaus Repository</name>
            <url>http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

when i try to change the mule-version from 3.4 to 3.6 i get this odd compile problem complaining about not founding one of my classes

this is what i am facing :

```
[12:55:21] Running: mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mule DroolsJBPM Application 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ESBDroolsRouter ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-mule-plugin:1.6:attach-test-resources (default-attach-test-resources) @ ESBDroolsRouter ---
[INFO] attaching test resource D:\MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\app
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ ESBDroolsRouter ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ ESBDroolsRouter ---
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[5,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[5,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[6,22] error: package org.jdom.filter does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[7,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[5,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[5,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[6,22] error: package org.jdom.filter does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[7,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[42,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[42,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[48,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[51,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[53,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[57,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[60,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[61,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[22,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[22,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[23,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[27,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[27,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[28,13] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[37,11] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 31 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.328 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-02T12:55:24+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/215M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ESBDroolsRouter: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[5,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[5,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[6,22] error: package org.jdom.filter does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[7,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[5,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[3,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[4,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[5,15] error: package org.jdom does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[6,22] error: package org.jdom.filter does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[7,21] error: package org.jdom.input does not exist
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[42,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[42,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[48,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[51,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[53,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[57,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[60,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\RuleXMLToDRL.java:[61,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[22,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[22,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[23,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[27,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[27,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[28,13] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \MuleWorkspace\ESBDroolsRouter\src\main\java\com\hamgam\hit\esb\XMLToDTO.java:[37,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: sometimes i get this error too : 
Error resolving version for plugin 'org.mule.tools:studio-maven-plugin'

Answer (score 0):

they changed several libraries in 3.6.0 (updated them) so there is a chance the class you are looking for may have move around.

Any ways the stack trace just shows missing packages, and I can find those in 3.5.1 and 3.6.0 too. Besides they are present in different jars. 
Could you please check which class is the one that is missing?

Comment: nah! i guess the missing package (jdom) is irrelevant to mule. i am using it somewhere else and as a matter of fact the jdom is very present in my classpath

Comment: well if you like, run mvn again with -e -X so we get more information. 
Shouldn't be nothing major really  but with the stack trace we have not much we can do :S

Comment: i have found the problem but not the solution (yet) the problem is maven is not updating the projects dependencies. and i cant find how to do it in Anypoit studio

Comment: Right click on your project
Maven support in studio
Populate maven repository 

You can also try an update, but the populate is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to update JDOM to the latest version.